# How do i return or convert String to object in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner to Java and I am having some issue with this code. I made this adres Object and I need it to return the adres string. It gives me an error message saying that it cannot convert String to Adres. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks alot

```
private Adres maakAdres() {



   String straat = adresScherm.getTfStraat();
   String plaats = adresScherm.getTfPlaats();
   String huisnr = adresScherm.getTfHuisNr();
   int IntHuisNr;
   try {
       IntHuisNr = Integer.parseInt(huisnr);
       String adres = plaats + ", " + straat + ", " + IntHuisNr;
       return adres;
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        adresScherm.getMelding().toonWaarschuwing("Het huisnummer moet een geheel getal zijn!");
   }

   if (Util.nullOrEmpty(straat) || Util.nullOrEmpty(plaats) || Util.nullOrEmpty(huisnr)) {
         adresScherm.getMelding().toonWaarschuwing("Niet alle gegevens zijn ingevuld");
         return null;
   }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Adres model object?

Comment: In your code, you are returning an `Adres` object. You need to create an instance of that and return that. Try `return new Adres(string)` assuming `Adres` has a string constructor.

Comment: If all you are returning is a `String` why not `private String maakAdres()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your method suggests that the methods is expected to return an Adres object, but you are trying to return a String object, which will generate a compile error. So you should create an Adres object , assign the values and return.